# What is difference between Selenium and Appium?

Tags: android, selenium, testing, automated-tests, appium

I can not see the exact difference between Selenium and Appium. Both of these server and framework is it right?

But I see lots of codes in github, when use appium, but the sample code contains of only selenium webdriver elements. Please somebody inform me about two tools. So we use appium and selenium together?

Thank you,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Appium is a casing for Selenium to test native apps (IOS and Android). From Appium [introduction](http://appium.io/introduction.html)

> ...wrapping the vendor-provided frameworks in one API, the WebDriver API. WebDriver (aka "Selenium WebDriver") specifies a client-server protocol (known as the JSON Wire Protocol). 
>   ...In other words, Appium & WebDriver clients are not technically "test frameworks" -- they are "automation libraries".
>
> ...WebDriver has become the de facto standard for automating web browsers, and is a W3C Working Draft. Why do something totally different for mobile? Instead we have extended the protocol with extra API methods useful for mobile automation.

Answer (score 10):

Basic difference between selenium and appium

**Appium :**

1. It is used in mobile application(android & ios).
2. Having specific driver eg : AndroidDriver and IOSDriver

If you want to run automation below 17 api in android you have to use selendroid for it.

**Selenium :**

1. It is used for mobile web application.
2. It is having web driver which runs on web application.

**Common Things :**

1. Both are opensource.
2. Both can be customize.
3. Both use Json-Wire protocol.

for details refer https://www.quora.com/Which-one-is-better-Selenium-or-Appium-for-app-testing

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, Appium is a mobile test automation framework (with a tool) that works for all: native, hybrid and mobile-web apps for iOS and Android. Appium is a great choice for test automation framework as it can be used for all these different app/web types. Basically, Appium derives its roots from Selenium and it uses JSONWireProtocol internally to interact with iOS and Android apps using Selenium’s WebDriver.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is meant for both when encaptulated with appium can be used for mobile automation as well as independently it is for web automation

Answer (score 0):

Appium :
Appium is an automation tool that was built for testing all types of applications whether mobile, web or hybrid applications. It is open-source software that was built using the C# programming language. Dan Cuellar developed the Appium in 2011, it has Apache 2 Licence. At first, it was known as iOSAuto but in 2013 it was named Appium when it came as open-source software.

Selenium :
Selenium is an open-source browser automation tool with Apache Licence 2.0 and it contains a large number of inbuilt libraries for web application testing. It is capable of automating nearly all the web browsers like Chrome, Brave, Firefox, etc. Its stable version was released in October 2021. It is a cross-platform software that was written using different programming languages like Python, Ruby, JavaScript, etc.